# Swift Constraint Broken When Re-Expanding Table View

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

So I have a 2 depth table view with sections and rows. When I expand the table view for the first time, everything's already good, but if I expand it for the 2nd, 3rd, .... times or scrolling when the sections expanded, then the left constraint for the rows sections is broken, for more details please see the image below:

[Please see this for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7sts.png)

It's my 3rd time I expanding the sections. And as you can see there're 2 rows that have broken left constraint. Here's my code:

```
func configureCell(data: FirstDepth) {
    self.firstDepthData = data
    self.firstDepthLabel.text = data.name
    self.firstDepthLabel.centerY(inView: contentView, leftAnchor: contentView.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 20)
}

func configureSecondCell(data: SecondDepth) {
    self.secondDepthData = data
    self.firstDepthLabel.text = data.name
    self.firstDepthLabel.centerY(inView: contentView, leftAnchor: contentView.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 50)
}
```

So the table view will call configureCell for the sections, and configureSecondCell for the rows, I've read maybe this is because of re-initialize the constraints, but how to only update the constant?

If needed, here's my code for the table view cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellFirstDepth.id, for: indexPath) as! CellFirstDepth
    
    if let firstDepthData = self.firstDepthData {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            // Call Cell for sections
            cell.configureCell(data: firstDepthData[indexPath.section])
        } else {
            // Call Cell for rows
            cell.configureSecondCell(data: firstDepthData[indexPath.section].child[indexPath.row - 1])
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

And this is my centerY function, just a code to make the element center to Y axis, and add anchor to left/right:

```
func centerY(inView view: UIView, leftAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, rightAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, paddingLeft: CGFloat? = nil, paddingRight: CGFloat? = nil, constant: CGFloat? = 0) {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: constant!).isActive = true
    
    if let leftAnchor = leftAnchor, let paddingLeft = paddingLeft {
        self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: paddingLeft).isActive = true
    } else if let rightAnchor = rightAnchor, let paddingRight = paddingRight {
        self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown us what your `.centerY(...)` function does, but pretty safe guess as to the problem.

It looks like you are adding a `.leftAnchor` constraint with a constant of `20`, and then the cell get's reused and you're adding ***another*** `.leftAnchor` constraint with a constant of `50`.

You need to edit your cell code to use a **single** constraint, and update its `.constant` property, instead of adding multiple constraints.

---

**Edit**

With a little searching, you can find many complete examples, but here's the general idea.

In your cell class, add this var property:

```
var labelLeftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then, in your cell class initialization, create that constraint:

```
labelLeftConstraint = self.firstDepthLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 0)
labelLeftConstraint.isActive = true
```

And, change your `configure` funcs like this:

```
func configureCell(data: FirstDepth) {
    self.firstDepthData = data
    self.firstDepthLabel.text = data.name
    labelLeftConstraint.constant = 20
    //self.firstDepthLabel.centerY(inView: contentView, leftAnchor: contentView.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 20)
}

func configureSecondCell(data: SecondDepth) {
    self.secondDepthData = data
    self.firstDepthLabel.text = data.name
    labelLeftConstraint.constant = 50
    //self.firstDepthLabel.centerY(inView: contentView, leftAnchor: contentView.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 50)
}
```

Now you will have only a **single** constraint, and your code will be setting its `.constant` instead of creating it over and over (which is what causes the problem).

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I forgot to put the function. But basically it's just a function to make the element to center in Y axis and add left/right anchor (I've put the code above). Do you think there's something wrong with my code there? Or I just need to update the constant instead of initiate more constraint? If so, how to update a constant in existing constraint? Thank you very much for your help also

Comment: @GilbertNicholas - see the **Edit** to my answer.